# making a template of TabPage?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using Tab controller with TabPages and to give same look and feel to all TabPages I want to extend existing TabPage, put some common controls in it and then use it as a parent of new TabPages so that all TabPages may have same look.

I have a little .Net experience but don't know much WinForms, kindly advice me how to do this.

Comment: Better to google it....During the implementation, if there comes problem, SO community is always there to help....

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you create a UserControl as a prototype content. Then, use [Visual Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z3efhd2.aspx) to extend the UserControl when you need to create a content for the next TabPage.